# jQuery when() on multiple animationend events

Tags: jquery, css, events, animation

I am using jquery on(animationend) to detect if an animation is finished and trigger a Callback. My problem is the animationend Event fires on each childelement im animating using CSS3.

Is there any way `$.when` to detect if there are all animationend events are fired and the animations are finished? how would that look like?

Im using css3 animations

My HTML for Example

```
  <div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  </div>
```

The parent and the child Containers have its own animation defined in CSS

```
  .parent.start-animation { animation: sample-animation 3s forwards }
  .parent.start-animation .child1 { animation: another-sample-animation 3s forwards }
  .parent.start-animation .child1 { animation: another-another-sample-animation 3s forwards }
```

My Javascript at the Moment

```
  function getAnimationEvent(){ 
      var t;
      var el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

      var animations = {
        "animation"      : "animationend",
        "OAnimation"     : "oAnimationEnd",
         "MozAnimation"   : "animationend",
         "WebkitAnimation": "webkitAnimationEnd"
       }

       for (t in animations){
         if (el.style[t] !== undefined){
            return animations[t];
          }
        }
    }


  var animationend = getAnimationEvent();

  $('.parent').addClass('start-animation').on(animationend, function(e) {
      // triggered 3 times - parent, child, child2


      // detect if it is the current element
      if ($(e.target).attr('class') == "parent") {
          // do somethng
      }

  });

 // I wont to do something like that
 $('.parent').addClass('start-animation').when(animationend).then(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Can we see your code or whatever you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling animated function for one class attribute so that is fire, Please single class for each function or call below:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(/*class name*/).click(
      $(this).parent(/*Parent class or ID*/).animate({/*Animation Effect or CSS Attribute here*/}, /*Event Firing Time*/);
})
/*
----------------------------
OR
----------------------------
*/
$( window ).load(function() {
   $(/*class name*/).click(
      $(this).parent(/*Parent class or ID*/).animate({/*Animation Effect or CSS Attribute here*/}, /*Event Firing Time*/);
  )
});
```

If you want to know more information about this please visit:
[Javascript Solution](http://programming-solution-code.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function that is called when the animation is done:

```
 ("#idOfElement).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 100, function () {
    //Do your magic here
    });
```

This seems to be the easiest, but with the code-snippet you provided it's hard to provide a complete solution for your problem.